# Portable C# IDE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, usb

Are there any IDEs for C# that are portable and will work off of a flash drive? Is there a way to make Visual Studio run as a portable application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the *portable* version SharpDevelop, PortableApps has a page [here](http://portableapps.com/node/30302). I've not tried it myself, so I'm not very sure if this would work as advertised.

Comment: do you know how to install the .net framwork 4 on usb too? it apparently requires .net 4 which the computers ill be using it on wont have :/

Comment: You could try looking at [this](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/laputa/archive/2008/08/16/sharpdevelop-on-a-memory-stick.aspx) and [this](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/t/11395.aspx) for some pointers, but from what I gather from those posts, getting it to be _fully_ portable seems a little tricky. Also note that it requires the *full* .NET Framework 4.0, just the Client Profile won't do.

Comment: ah, i tried the first link, that helped, thanks. The only problem is its ONLY code, it doesnt have a drag and drop form designer, or maybe i just cant find it. other than that it works fine

Comment: AFAIK SharpDevelop has a WinForms designer. See [here](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/pages/FeatureTourVisuallyDesigningForms.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it with visual studio, but VMware ThinApp might be able to make a portable installation.

http://hacktolive.org/wiki/Make_portable_applications_with_VMware_ThinApp